# Is there an open database of middle, and high schools outside of the United States (international)?

Tags: data-request, academia

For a project I am looking for a database of middle and high schools outside of the United States.. something similar to that of NCES or CCD. We need a list of these and an unique identifier such as the ones used by the College Board or such.

Comment: It may help if you can give a bit more detail. For example, what countries are you looking for data on? It might help to read [what makes a good data request](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/a/285/19374) for some tips on what information to provide to maximise your chances of getting the information you want.

Comment: What college Board are you referring to ?